# Does C# have a built in way to throttle a function's number of calls?

Tags: c#

I've got a single function that executes an HTTP request. I use this function all throughout a simple program I've written.

I need to throttle these HTTP requests though so that I do not exceed rate limits. In the JavaScript world, there's a really handy [third party library](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) that provides a `throttle` function that returns a new function that calls your own function but will queue up the calls so that they only occur *X* times per minute or whatever.

Is there a built-in C# way of doing this? If not, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can easily do this with `Task.Delay(...)` or manually by calculating a time difference since the last call which is greater than your treshold value.

Comment: @SharpShade doesn't work if the call frequency approaches or exceeds timer resolution which is ~15ms. Also, this does not allow for concurrent calls.

Comment: I assume though since he actually wants to throttle the requesting method, that the frequency is beyond the timer resolution. Especially since you probably have at least ~5+ ms (depending on your server) to actually handle the request.

Comment: One best practise that is popularly used in microservice architecture is [Poly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly) The more generic solution is to use a Queue. If you are worried about threading, consider a [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-7.0) The implementation is simple, but you will have to write a dozen lines of code yourself to package this into a reusable component for your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way. You'll need to find a library or implement this yourself.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Reactive Extensions, you can take advantage of the `Observable.Throttle()` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400(v=vs.103).aspx

The Reactive Extensions page can be found at http://reactivex.io/

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have said, you would have to implement this yourself. Fortunately, it's fairly easy. Personally, I would create a `Queue<ObjectWithYourFunction'sArguments>`. You might then have a `ThrottledFunction` that queues stuff up and, if needed, starts a background task to wait the appropriate length of time.

Totally untested example code:

```
class ThrottleMyFunction
{
    private class Arguments
    {
        public int coolInt;
        public double whatever;
        public string stringyThing;
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<Arguments> _argQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Arguments>();
    private Task _loop;

    //If you want to do "X times per minute", replace this argument with an int and use TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1/waitBetweenCalls)
    public void ThrottleMyFunction(TimeSpan waitBetweenCalls)
    {
        _loop = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Arguments args;
            while (true)
            {
                if (_argQueue.TryDequeue(out args))
                    FunctionIWantToThrottle(args.coolInt, args.whatever, args.stringyThing);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(waitBetweenCalls);

        });
    }

    public void ThrottledFunction(int coolerInt, double whatevs, string stringy)
    {
        _argQueue.Enqueue(new Arguments() { coolInt = coolerInt, whatever = whatevs, stringyThing = stringy });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a `ConcurrentQueue`. It's a web application so you'll be enqueuing items on multiple threads and dequeueing on probably still another.

Comment: Good suggetsion, @ScottHannen. I was kinda thinking about doing that anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this but by its very nature testing it would be a little complex. (IOW it is not tested.)

The presumption is that you have an `Action<TParameters>` to call, so that action is passed as parameter to the constructor. Then to execute, you call `Enqueue(TParameters parameters)`.

It's going to enqueue your item and begin processing the queue (unless the queue is already being processed.) Each execution increments a counter, and when the counter reaches the maximum number of executions per interval then execution stops.

There's also a timer for the specified interval. When that timer elapses the number of executions is reset and the queue is processed (unless it's already being processed.) That way items that have been waiting for the end of the interval are processed.

This is a very literal interpretation of your requirements. It's not spreading calls out evenly across an interval, with time in between them. It means that if you can only make a given call 3 times in one second, it will make the first 3 calls immediately and then wait until the second elapses before making 3 more calls. The objective is to use whatever capacity you have without waiting, and then wait for more capacity to become available and use it without waiting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace Throttler
{
    public abstract class ExecutionThrottler<TParameters> : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action<TParameters> _action;
        private readonly int _executionsPerInterval;
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TParameters> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TParameters>();
        private bool _processingQueue;
        private readonly object _processingQueueLock = new object();
        private int _executionsSinceIntervalStart;
        private readonly Timer _timer;
        bool _disposed;

        protected ExecutionThrottler(Action<TParameters> action, TimeSpan interval, int executionsPerInterval)
        {
            _action = action;
            _executionsPerInterval = executionsPerInterval;
            _timer = new Timer(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Elapsed += OnIntervalEnd;
        }

        public void Enqueue(TParameters parameters)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(parameters);
        }

        private void TryProcessQueue()
        {
            if (_processingQueue) return;
            lock (_processingQueueLock)
            {
                if (_processingQueue) return;
                _processingQueue = true;
                try
                {
                    ProcessQueue();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _processingQueue = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProcessQueue()
        {
            TParameters dequeuedParameters;
            while ((_executionsSinceIntervalStart < _executionsPerInterval) && _queue.TryDequeue(out dequeuedParameters))
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _executionsSinceIntervalStart);
                _action.Invoke(dequeuedParameters);
            }
        }


        private void OnIntervalEnd(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _executionsSinceIntervalStart = 0;
            TryProcessQueue();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ~ExecutionThrottler()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: edited to remove unnecessary use of `Interlocked` to ensure atomic read/write. The only operation that requires it is incrementing the count of executed operations.

Comment: Update to this: I overused `Interlocked`.  `_executionsSinceIntervalStart`  can be an `int`, and all of the other operations besides incrementing are already atomic.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with little code by creating a timer and a handle to do the trick, here is a how to link http://sstut.com/csharpdotnet/javascript-timers-equivalent.php

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no built-in throttling in .Net Framework. You need to build your own or find existing library.

I think the closest you can get withinn Framework is setting limits on number threads for calls like `Parallel.Foreach`.